# Read text file with multiple JSON messages

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have a text file which contains multiple JSON messages. There is no separator except new line. I have a method which will take JSON string and deserialize it to some object type.

How can I read text file and iterate through each Json string so that it can be deserialized?

Below is the method for deserialize:

```
public static T JsonDeserialize<T>(string jsonString)
{
    DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString));
    T obj = (T)ser.ReadObject(ms);
    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing i can think of is to loop through each character and count brackets. When the bracket count is zero it will add the combined string to the list. At the end you will have a list of individual JSON strings.

```
public List<string> GetJsonItems()
{
    int BracketCount = 0;
    string ExampleJSON = new StreamReader(@"c:\Json.txt").ReadToEnd();
    List<string> JsonItems = new List<string>();
    StringBuilder Json = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (char c in ExampleJSON)
    {
        if (c == '{')
            ++BracketCount;
        else if (c == '}')
            --BracketCount;
        Json.Append(c);

        if (BracketCount == 0 && c != ' ')
        {
            JsonItems.Add(Json.ToString());
            Json = new StringBuilder();

        }
    }
    return JsonItems;    
}
```

EDIT: Changed the code to use StringBuilder and its much faster now. Parsed out a JSON file of 2MB almost instantly.

Comment: This is going to explode if `ExampleJSON` contains a string with `"}"`, which is a valid json. For example `{"key": "value}"}`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use **jsonReader.SupportMultipleContent** Property.
It doesn't matter the separation between the messages newline(s), tab or space(s).

SupportMultipleContent  sets a value true/false (default is false) indicating whether multiple pieces of JSON content can be read from a continuous stream without error.

Example:

```
public static void Main()
{   
    string json = @"
    {
        'Name': 'foo',
        'Id': 123
    }{
        'Name': 'bar',
        'Id': 456
    }
    
    //more new line
    {
        'Name': 'jar',
        'Id': 789
    }
    ";

     var persons = DeserializeObjects<Person>(json).ToList();
     Console.WriteLine(persons.Count());
     foreach ( var person in persons)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("id: {0}, Name: {1}",person.Id, person.Name);
    }
```

}

```
    static IEnumerable<T> DeserializeObjects<T>(string input)
    {
        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        using (var strreader = new StringReader(input)) 
        using (var jsonreader = new JsonTextReader(strreader))
        {
                //you should use this line
                jsonreader.SupportMultipleContent = true;
                while (jsonreader.Read()) 
                {                       
                    yield return  serializer.Deserialize<T>(jsonreader);
                }
            
        }
    }
     

    class Person
    {
      public int Id {get;set;}
      public string  Name {get;set;}
    }
```

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ixWYGG)

output:

> 3
>
> id: 123, Name: foo
>
> id: 456, Name: bar
>
> id: 789, Name: jar

Answer (score 1):

You can also split your text file and iterate through each single JSON part.

Something like this:

```
void ReadJsonWithLinebreaks(string jsonFilePath)
{
        string jsonFileContent = File.ReadAllText(jsonFilePath);
        string[] jsonContentSplitted = jsonFileContent.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());

        // ... iterate through array that contains your JSON content
}
```

Edit:
Use `File.ReadAllLines()` instead of `File.ReadAllText` if your JSON-file comes with linebreaks.

Answer (score 1):

if your Json strings are separated by new lines you can iterate through all lines and parse them with the following code:

```
List<YourClass> objects = new List<YourClass>();
String[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("path\to\file.txt");
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    try
    {
        var obj = JsonDeserialize<YourClass>(line);
        objects.Add(obj);
    }
    catch (Exception) { }
}
```

If this doesn't help you, please post a sample file.

Comment: Eating exeptions is a _very_ bad thing in my opinion.

Comment: Depends on your needs. But this ist just a quick snippet and I doesn't know what the author needs to do if the deserialization fails. So this code is a hint to the solution and not the code he should copy and paste.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the `StreamReader` class. This has a method `ReadLine()` that will return you `json` messages one at a time. You can either call your `JsonDeserialize` function as you read the file, or put all the messages into a list and deserialize them later.

```
List<MyClass> deserializedObjects = new List<MyClass>();
using(var reader = new StreamReader(pathToFile)){
    while(!reader.EndOfStream){
        deserializedObjects.Add(JsonDeserialize<MyClass>(reader.ReadLine()));
    }
}
```